# How to determine if an empirical probability is statistically different to 50/50?

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, statistical-inference, conditional-probability

I have $431$ observations of nursing care and am interested to know if touching a patient influenced their handwashing compliance. I have a column for Handwash (Yes/No) and one for Patient contact (Yes/No).

I calculated the probability of Handwash (H) given Patient contact (C) $\Rightarrow \mathbb{P}(H\cap C) = \dfrac{115}{431}$. Fine, now how do I treat that? So how can I put some statistical value or inference to this probability? (Any suggestions or ideas at your discretion)

Comment: Be careful: Do you mean that "Given that there was patient contact, the probability of handwash is $115/431$"? Because that would be $P(H|C)$, which is something else than $P(H \cap C)$.

Comment: Ah now that's what I'd been pondering too, would you mind giving a very quick explanation of the difference in this context. IE if I had only these two columns of data how would you calculate them both?

Comment: Suppose $A$ cases are with both handwashing and patient contact, $B$ cases for only handwashing, $C$ cases for patient contact and $D$ cases for neither handwashing not patient contact, so that $A + B + C + D = 431$. Then $P(H \cap C)$ would be $A/431$, ($A$ cases out of all $431$ cases), but for $P(H|C)$ you'd get $A/(A + C)$, ($A$ cases out of the $A + C$ cases with patient contact).

Comment: If you observe the subjects for a long time and record (say in 10 min intervals) did they wash hands (H), did they have patient contact(C), then $P(H\cap C)$, which is the probability of both,  would be the fraction of *all* lines that have yes in both columns.  $P(H|C)$, which is probability of washing given contact would be the fraction of lines that have yes in both columns *out of the lines that have yes in the $H$ column*.

Comment: Super! Yes I can visualise the first bit. Which part of the Venn diagram is $P(H|C)$? I just cant quite visualise what P(H|C) means in real terms... let me put it more succinctly, I want to investigate whether touching the patient has any effect on handwashing (order is actually not observed at this stage), so which probability do you think it should be? IF later I do observe the order, does this change anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hypothesis is that handwashing is like a coin flip-it is independently done or not with $50\%$ probability.  The variance of a coin flip is $\frac 14$, so the variance of $431$ coin flips is $\frac {431}4$ and (using the normal approximation) the standard deviation is the square root of this, about $10.4$.  You are about $10$ standard deviations away.

Comment: Ah ya, so we're talking a Bernoulli distribution with variance p(1-p)? But where does the 40% come from? Is that what @TMM was referring to or is this something different?

Comment: @user1134241:  I was saying that you are checking whether you can eliminate the hypothesis that after contact the person flips a coin and washes or not if they get heads, independently of who it is or whether they washed last time.

Comment: Yes I see what you mean (let's assume this is true). But where did your 40% value come from?

Comment: @user1134241:  it was a typo for $50\%$.  Fixed.

Comment: Is this still valid if I was interested in $P(H|C)$? Incidentally which part of the Venn diagram does the latter constitute? cheers

Comment: @user1134241:  If $\frac {115}{431}$ is your $P(H|C)$ data, yes.  The numerator for $P(H|C)$ and $P(H\cap C)$ is the same, it is the overlap of $H$ and $C$.  For $P(H|C)$ you divide by all the C's while for $P(H\cap C)$ you divide by the whole universe.

Comment: $\frac{115}{431}$ is the count of nurses who washed their hands and touched a patient. (so I thought this was $P(H\cap C)$ I cant see what information $P(H|C)$ would provide (it seems abstract). Or am I completely wrong?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8122/discussion-between-ross-millikan-and-user1134241)